# Typescript error when trying to get computed style value dynamically

Tags: typescript

I am getting `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.` for the following piece of code on the `[value + 'Top']`. How would I go about setting a type for this?

Simple example:

```
const value = 'margin'

const div = document.querySelector('div') as HTMLElement

const style = getComputedStyle(div)

console.log(style[value + 'Top'])
```

I can just do `[value + 'Top' as any]` or `[value + 'Top' as keyof {}]` but obviously this seems wrong. What is the approach here?

I am trying to set up a function that will get either the margins, paddings or borderWidths of an element. But I don't need all of the values at any given time so I figured I would try to dynamically get them.

Full function example:

```
function getElementComputedStyle(element: HTMLElement, value: string) {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(element)

  if (!style) {
    return {
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      totals: {
        vertical: 0,
        horizontal: 0,
      },
    }
  }

  const top = parseFloat(style[value + 'Top'])
  const bottom = parseFloat(style[value + 'Bottom'])
  const left = parseFloat(style[value + 'Left'])
  const right = parseFloat(style[value + 'Right'])
  const totals = {
    vertical: top + bottom,
    horizontal: left + right,
  }

  return {
    top,
    bottom,
    left,
    right,
    totals,
  }
}

export default getElementComputedStyle
```

Note I have also tried typing the value to `value: 'margin' | 'padding' | 'border'` but that didn't work either.

Comment: If your function should only be called with ```"margin"```, ```"padding"``` or ```"borderWidth"```, first step would be to set the type of the second parameter accordingly: ```function getElementComputedStyle(element: HTMLElement, value: "margin" | "padding" | "borderWidth")```. I am not sure if TS is now already able to see that this property would exist, but at least a human does, so give it a try.

Comment: @Islingre Sorry I guess I should have put that I already tried that and it didn't work. I still get the same error. I will edit the question. Thanks

Comment: Okay, use it anyways and then combine it with the template strings as already mentioned in some answers. Then it works as expected. I guess TS widens the type to ```string``` everytime it sees the ```+``` while it does not so for template strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with string literals. Maybe because typescript is smarter with them.

```
style[value + 'Top'] // does not work
style[`${value}Top`] // works
```

Comment: try `const value = "margin"`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue(`${value}Top`);
```

which will happily accept a string parameter ...